# substringing on a character in db2

Tags: sql, db2, substring

I have two columns X and Y where the values could be as below:

```
  X        Y
--------------  
 rob     one.1 
 rob     two.2
 rob     abc.3
 rob     pqr.4
 harry   lmn.3
 harry   lkja.4
 harry   lkjs.6
```

I am querying on column X. That is

```
select Y where X='rob'
select Y where X='harry'
```

I want to write a query on above columns where the output will be strings like "rob # 1,2,3,4" and "harry # 3,4,6"

So first part of the result string will be the X value followed by a constant # followed by the numbers in Y after '.' dot.

So rob gets 1,2,3,4 and harry has 3,4,6

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it using aggregate functions in db2:

```
concat('Harry # ',substr( xmlserialize( xmlagg( xmltext( concat( ', ', substr(myTable.salary, locate('.',myTable.salary)+1) ) ) ) as varchar( 1024 ) ), 3 ))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of a concatination:

Its the way to go with your problem..

SQL CONCAT() function is used to concatenate two or more strings. MySQL allows you concatenate more than two strings while other force exactly two. Here is the syntax:

```
CONCAT(expression)
```

Here is the query to concat employee name and his salary in MySQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT(name,':',salary) as name_salary
    FROM employees
```

Here is the output:

```
name_salary    
----------------
jack:3000.00   
mary:2500.00   
newcomer:2000.00
anna:2800.00   
Tom:2700.00    
foo:4700.00
```

Comment: What you will be wanting to do is concat the subquery (select Right(CHARINDEX(Y,'.')) from TABLE)

Comment: The solution you have given is a simple concatenation... However, the requirement is much more complex.. where in the salary part is coming from three different rows and the output should be name:sal1,sal2,sal3 --- in that format...